# Set Read only permission for the owner

Tags: 20.04, permissions

**Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS**

In the graphical interface I'm unable to change permissions. This is just a CSV file on a disc separate from the system one.

[image]

I tried to change the access for owner to Read only, but it immediately switches back to Read and write.

Could you help me understand why it happens and how to cope with this problem?

Comment: Most times, I have seen this behavior, it is not allowed at filesystem-level. Not all filesystems understand unix permissions. For example If you are trying to change permissions on a vFAT USBStick/SDCard, it won't work and shows the permission your user got in the filesystem instead of the file.

Comment: You seem to be right. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times, I have seen this behavior, it is not allowed at filesystem-level. Not all filesystems understand unix permissions.
For example If you are trying to change permissions on a vFAT USBStick/SDCard, it won't work and shows the permission your user got in the filesystem instead of the file.